# How to make complex Firestore rules work fine with maps and lists?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently having **a lot** of trouble setting up complex Firestore rules, but nothing worked so far and I would love if someone could help.

This is my root database structure:

- groups
- user_access
- meetings

Where user_access has email address as key, and an *object/list/value* (more on that later) with the groupId he can access followed by the level of permission.
Every meeting has a groupId (where it belong).

So, I would like a rule to: check if the current groupId value from meetings is in the document at user_access with the current email address as key.

I thought about doing this rule (simplified below):

```
service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
          match /meetings/{meetingId} {

          function correctUser() {
            return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/access/$(request.auth.token.email)).data.obj[get(/databases/$(database)/documents/meetings/$(meetingId)).data.groupId] == "leader" 
          }

          allow read: if correctUser();
          allow write: if correctUser();
     }
}
```

But it doesn't work.. And I'm not sure why.

I tried making a list:

```
function correctUser() {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/meetings/$(meetingId)).data.groupId in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/access/$(request.auth.token.email)).data.list
}
```

But it also didn't work and I'm not sure why.

The best case scenario would be using a list of objects (a map), key(id),value(permission). Is that possible? Worst case scenario I can use a list for each different permission, or even put all the ids as value (I'll probably never reach the 20k fields limit).

So, I have two questions:

- **First**, how can I make my rule(s) work?
- **Second**, how do I call values from wildcards from inside fields? For example, on the example above with {meetingId}, how would I use this meetingId as a key? (...).data.meetingId? (...).data[$(meetingId)]? I found it very confusing and bad documented. What about on maps? Same thing?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're defining custom functions but never calling them.  If you are, please show more completely your rules that do so.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#custom_functions

Comment: Hey Doug! I probably simplified too much above, but I'm calling. This is the full rule: https://pastebin.com/nEpVD5Gd . Could you also tell how the right way to call wildcards from fields (second question above)? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me weeks to find out, but what I ultimately wanted and worked was:

```
 function isLeader() {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/access/$(request.auth.token.email)).data[request.resource.data.groupId] == "leader"
        || get(/databases/$(database)/documents/access/$(request.auth.token.email)).data[resource.data.groupId] == "leader"
    }
```

There is difference between **request.resource.data.groupId** and **resource.data.groupId** which I didn't know and was killing my requests, sometimes read, sometimes write. Glad it works now.

Comment: would you mind to explain the difference? I might have the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343229/q-firestore-security-error-missing-or-insufficient-permissions) at hand.

Comment: now that there is a simulator on Firestore, things might be a lot easier to debug. resource references the document which is already on the database, while Request.resource references the new document, inbound data. Am I clear enough?