# Q: Firestore Security Error: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm currently using Firestore for database and ran in to insufficient permission error. What I don't understand is why `isPartner()` will work when my path is

> users/{uid}

but give me permission error when it's

> object/{objectID}

***Security Rules***

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{uid} {
        allow read: if isSignedIn(); 
      allow write: if isOwner(uid) || isPartner();

      match /object/{objectID} {
      allow read, write : if isPartner() || isOwner(uid);
      }

      function isOwner(userID) {
        return request.auth.uid == userID
      }

      function isPartner() {
      return resource.data.partnerUID == request.auth.uid
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is your second match supposed to be nested within the first?  Maybe check your indentation, as it's not helping readability here.

Comment: yes it is suppose to be nested. Upon further research, my issue could be cause by  not understanding the difference between request.resource.data and resource.data. Is it possible to provide some example for me to understand the difference and how to use it?